# How to deploy an ERC20 from within a contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

Is there a way to automate an ERC20 token deploy? Can a contract receive some parameters to configure the new token and then deploy it returning the new token address?

I'm trying to create a contract that speaks with a dapp which instructs the contract to create and then deploy a given ERC20 token with the given parameters (name, sym, decimals...)

Is this possible?

I've found that a Dapp can deploy a contract:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/deploying-a-smart-contract-using-dapp

But can a contract deploy a contract? Is this too pricy?

Answer (score 0):

> But can a contract deploy a contract?

Yes. A contract can deploy a contract.

See [for example Uniswap v2 UniswapV@Factory](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L31) deploying pair contracts using `CREATE2` (deterministic deployed contract addresses).

> Is this too pricy?

This is a business model question and cannot be answered based on the information you provided in the question.